# OpenCL option not available in Blender 2.78c running on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: rendering, gpu, linux, opencl

[image: cycles compute setting]

- Dedicated GPU: AMD Radeon R5 M330 (HAINAN), Drivers: radeon + Mesa 17.2.0 obtained from the `padoka` PPA.
- Blender Version 2.78c downloaded from blender.org

Tried running with `DRI_PRIME=1`, running as root, and both at the same time, but none of those worked.

OpenCL rendering with this GPU works on Windows 10 so I am sure my GPU is supported.

Comment: Is above screen shot from user settings ?

Comment: @BlenderForYou yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 years later, I found out that it was just because I didn't have OpenCL drivers. I'm using Arch now, so all I had to do is to install `opencl-amd` from the AUR, and `ocl-icd`. This still doesn't change the fact that GCN 1.0 support was dropped in 2.79 as Sniperbeer mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

As of march 2017 GCN 1.0 is no longer supported for gpu rendering.
Because the R5 M330 is using that architecture you won't be able to use it anymore in blender.

---

Sources:

- https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Source/Render/Cycles/OpenCL#Current_issues_and_limitations
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Radeon_RX_300_series#Mobile_products

Comment: How unfortunate! I think you should edit your question and replace "As of march 2017 GCN 1.0 is no longer supported for gpu rendering" to " All versions made after March 2017 do not support GCN 1.0 for GPU rendering".

Comment: But the first link you pointed says that: "If you have such a card, use Blender 2.78c downloadable here: http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.78/"